# Unboxing to larger value type

Tags: c#, .net, boxing, unboxing

The following code leads to an `InvalidCastException`.

```
  object x = (short) 1;
  int y = (int) x;
```

I know that I could cast `x` first to a `short` and then to an `int`, although that is not an option, as the type of the boxed value is not known (but it is definetly smaller than an `int`).

How can I work around the exception when unboxing to a type, that is larger than the boxed type?

**Edit:** 
I solved my problem by using the `dynamic` type (with all the performance implications)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [only unbox an object to its exact type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx).

Instead, you should call `Convert.ToInt32()`, which will work with any numeric type.